# How to use ngx_http_access_module?

Tags: nginx, ngx-http-access-module

Am I using **ngx_http_access_module** correctly? My attempts are as follows, always modifications of `nginx/conf.d/my.conf`.

**Attempt 1 -  allow/deny in main context**

```
allow 1.2.3.4;
deny all;

server {
  ...
}
```

nginx starts but the ips are not restricted...

**Attempt 2 -  allow/deny in http section**

```
http {
  allow 1.2.3.4;
  deny all;
}

server {
  ...
}
```

Ends up with:

> "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/my.conf

Comment: Remove the http block, because it already exists in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add `deny all;` inside the server block

Comment: You were right! Do you mind to post an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the http block, because it already exists in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add `deny all;` inside the server block